# Tagging project with dependent subproject repos in Meson?

Tags: git, release, meson-build

I'm using [Meson build system](https://mesonbuild.com/) for my project.
The main project repository has several [Meson subprojects](https://mesonbuild.com/Subprojects.html), which are separate repositories (defined in the `.wrap` files).

Example of wrap-git file:

```
[wrap-git]
url = https://github.com/libfoobar/libfoobar.git
revision = main
```

How do I tag a release of my project, considering subprojects and their repo revisions stated in the `.wrap` files?

This is the workflow I had in mind:

- tag subproject repositories (those are self-contained, no dependencies)
- create a `release-v1.0.0` branch for the main project repository
- change `.wrap` files in the `release-v1.0.0` branch so they point to subproject's tags (f.e. `revision = v1.2.3`
- tag main project `v1.0.0` from branch `release-v1.0.0`

Is this the proper way to go when tagging project with dependent repos in Meson?